# Function B returns null when called from function A, but returns correct value when logged within function B

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

please refer to the code below:

```js
    function getGdriveLinks() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
      const fileNames = sheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues();
      const mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID');
      for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.filter(String).length; i++){
        var fileName = fileNames[i][0].toString();
        var fileLink = getGdriveLink(fileName,mainFolder);
        Logger.log(fileLink);
      }
    }
    
    function getGdriveLink(searchFileName,folder){
      var mainFiles = folder.getFiles(); 
      while (mainFiles.hasNext()){
        var file = mainFiles.next();
        if(file.getName().indexOf(searchFileName) != -1){
          Logger.log(file.getUrl());
          return file.getUrl();
        }
      }
      var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
        while (subFolders.hasNext()){
          var subFolder = subFolders.next();
          getGdriveLink(searchFileName,subFolder);
        }
    }
```

Basically, the aim is to get the filenames in `C2:C` of `Test` sheet, find each of these in the `'Folder ID'`, and then return their URL. The URL is returned correctly when I log it from `getGdriveLink(searchFileName,folder)` using `Logger.log(file.getUrl())`. However, it returns `null` via the `Logger.log(fileLink)` when the result goes back to `getGdriveLinks()` function. Is there anything I'm missing? We're using a corporate domain if that's something to consider. Hoping for your guidance. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a `return` on the recursive call.

Comment: @Pointy So the `return file.getUrl();` isn't enough, and I need another one after the `getGdriveLink(searchFileName,subFolder);`, is this it? I thought that when calling `getGdriveLink(searchFileName,subFolder);`, it's running its own `return file.getUrl();` which would be enough. So this isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way and avoid recursion altogether

```
function getPathAllDrivesFromId(fileid) {
  var ids = [{id:fileid,name:DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getName()}];
  let r;
  do {
    r = Drive.Files.get(fileid,{supportsAllDrives:true,supportsTeamDrives:true});
    if(r.parents.length > 0) {
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r.parents[0]));
      ids.push({id:r.parents[0].id,name:DriveApp.getFolderById(r.parents[0].id).getName()});
      fileid = r.parents[0].id
    }
  }while (r.parents.length > 0);
  if(ids[ids.length - 1].name == "Drive") {
    ids[ids.length - 1].name = Drive.Drives.get(ids[ids.length - 1].id).name;
  }
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  let path = ids.map(obj => obj.name).flat().reverse().join(' / ')
  //Logger.log(path);
  return path;
}

function getGdriveLinks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  const ns = sh.getRange('C2:C' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID');
  const result = [["Filename", "Id", "Url", "path"]];
  ns.forEach(n => {
    let files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(n);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      let path = getPathAllDrivesFromId(file.getId());
      if (~path.indexOf(folder.getName())) {
        result.push([file.getName(), file.getId(), file.getUrl(), path]);
      }
    }
  })
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```